# How to make scheduled post in microsoft teams using Adaptive Card

Tags: adaptive-cards

I have created json string for Adaptive Card with notification like following.

Then, I want to post this at specific datetime because I do not want o notify me at night.

So, I look for json string that we can set datetime.

But, I can not find out.

Do you have any suggestion for this?

Regard,

```
[
    "type" => "message",
    "attachments" => [
        [
            "contentType" => "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
            "content" => [
                "type" => "AdaptiveCard",
                "body" => [
                    [
                        "type" => "TextBlock",
                        "size" => "large",
                        "weight" => "Bolder",
                        "text" => "Title",
                    ],
                    [
                        "type" => "TextBlock",
                        "text" => "<at>test@test.jp<at>",
                        "color" => "attention",
                        "wrap" => true,
                    ]
                ],
                "$schema" => "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
                "version" => "1.5",
                "msteams" => [
                    "width" => "Full",
                    "entities" => [
                        [
                            "type" => "mention",
                            "text" => "<at>Notify</at>",
                            "mentioned" => [
                                "id" => "test@test.jp",
                                "name" => "@test",
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
]
```